# Get json contents with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In a JQuery variable I have, for example:

`var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California"];`

In a `states.json` file I have exactly the same content:

`["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California"]`

How can I get the contents of this file and keep it to a variable with JQuery?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('./states.json',function(data){

        //alert(data); //it works!

        //opa=$.parseJSON(data); //ReferenceError: opa is not defined - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

        opa=data; //ReferenceError: opa is not defined

    });

    alert(opa); //it doesn't work

});
```

---

UPDATE:

A screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all verify your JSON data comming or not from Server.
Use `console.log(data);`
and check..

if it `JSON` is coming then You should use `var opa;` before `JSON`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var opa; //Try with this now
        $.getJSON('./states.json',function(data){                               
            opa=data;       
           alert(opa); //use Alert it will work.              
       });
   });
```

**OR use Function**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var opa; //Try with this now
            $.getJSON('./states.json',function(data){                               
                opa=data;       
               getDataAnywhere(opa);        
           });
       }); 

function getDataAnywhere(opa){

//do anything with opa

}
```

Comment: it is verified your json is coming from server ?

Comment: Well I have just noticed that the content in the json file were with double quotes and not single as I put in the example. I don't know if this makes any difference. And yes, Firebug is showing the json content just fine.

Comment: Only the function aproach worked, thank you. By the way, jsonlint.com said the json file was valid...

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because is asynchronous code. You cannot use variable opa outside getJSON so you need to assign data to a global context variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var globalContext;
    $.getJSON('./states.json',function(data){   

        globalContext=data;         
    });

   });
   alert(globalContext);
```

});

Comment: Please, why can I see with Firebug the data and not via alert?

Comment: @Roger. The alert must wait until the data from states.json arrives, because getJSON is asynchronous, as nmos pointed out or do your work in the callback.

Comment: I am testing the code in my localhost server... And Firebug is able to see the response... I must be missing something here.

Comment: Firebug is itself asynchronous and it shows references rather than snapshots, as I stated above code inside getJSON is async so it is outside main scope